How to Get Microsoft .NET SDK 6.0 in the msix format
I am doing this on a non-admin user and I am trying to get .NET 6.0 Sdk as MSIX.
I tried dotnet-install script but nothing worked. And when I ran dotnet --list-sdks but there was none. There were only runtimes installed so I am puzzled.

trying to get .NET 6.0 Sdk as MSIX --> we can go to the official site to download the SDK, but it looks like there's no .MSIX installation package. There might be somewhere else providing .MSIX format, but we still recommend official installation.
In the meantime, I download and install the .net SDK manually, after that I can see it if I run dotnet --list-sdks command.


